# Drag down formula - need alternative

Tags: excel, formula

I've got row that look like this [image] . I need to make really long row with for example - 9milion days. is there any alternative for draging down formula to cell far away from starting point? I want to ask excel to automatic fill all cells in row till it acheve specific day. is it possible? If yes please tell me how :) Thank you!

Comment: There aren't 9 million columns... But you could simply use a formula (for example in B1: `=A1+1`), CTRL+C the formula, END, RIGHT, SHIFT+END+LEFT, CTRL+V. That will fill the whole row. You can then delete what you don't need.

Comment: Why so many days? That's roughly 25000 years. Are you planning something for your 820th something generation? Excel has a limit of around 1 million rows by the way, and even less columns.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a database instead of a spreadsheet...

Comment: @JNYRanger Let's hope he doesn't try creating a table with 9 million columns!

Comment: @crush oh man would that be painful to query on!

Comment: ok. lets make it simpler - I need only 100 days.

Comment: @user2686462 is this a programming based question or are you just asking about Excel functions?  If the latter please check on SuperUser.com instead of StackOverflow

Comment: @assylias has you covered either way, but in any case, 100 days is much simpler than "9 million" days. Dragging down formulas doesnt take long by any means, even for let's say 10,000 rows, so streamlining that shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: You don't even need formulas to do this. Just filling down will give the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Type the first date in Cell A1.
- Click into the **Name Box** (to the left of the **Formula Bar**); type A1:A200 and press Enter to select these cells. (You could try 9 million but it won't work!).
- On the **Home Tab**, **Editing Group**, choose **Fill** and **Series**. Choose the Type of Date and Step of 1.

Alternatively, if you know the specific date that you wish to stop at:

- Type the first date in Cell A1.
- Just click in this single cell.
- Choose **Fill** as described above.
- Choose **Series in - Columns**
- The Step should be 1 and type the date that you want to stop at as the **Stop value**.

If you are dragging across, rather than down, then adjust these steps accordingly.

Comment: This is obviously not a programming solution but I've posted my answer as it may be useful to others.